# Closed-form expression for maximization problem with binary decision variable

Tags: optimization, closed-form

I have a maximization problem as follows:

$$\max_{\mathbf{p}} w\text{ln}\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^I p_ia_i\Bigg) - \sum_{i=1}^{I}p_id_i, $$

where $p_i \in \{0,1\}$ is binary variable and $\sum_{i=1}^I p_i = 1$. I need to find optimal $p^*_i$, where

$$\mathbf{p}^* = \arg \max_{\mathbf{p}} w\text{ln}\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^I p_ia_i\Bigg) - \sum_{i=1}^{I}p_id_i$$.

Is there any way to obtain the closed-form of $p^*_i$ as the function of $w$, $a_i$, and $d_i$?

Answer (score 1):

It is just $p_i=[i=i^*]$, where $i^*=\arg\max_i (w\ln a_i-d_i)$. The square brackets here are Iverson notation.

Comment: Do you mind to explain your answer in more detail? Note that the maximization has 2 constraints: $p_i \in \{0,1\}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^I p_i = 1$. Is it possible to find the closed-form of $i^*$ without using $\arg \max$?

Comment: For example, when I want to obtain $p_1$, I may need $a_j$ and $d_j$ values, where $j \neq 1, j \in \mathcal{I}$ since $i=1$ depends on $j$ as well.

Comment: You have a sum of binary variables equal to 1, so there are exactly $l$ solutions, each of the form $p_i=1$ for exactly one $i$. The objective for solution $i$ is $w\ln a_i-d_i$.  To maximize, just take one pass through this list of $l$ objective values and take the best.